# Blocks from Drupal footer not included in sub theme footer template

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-blocks, drupal-templates

I have a Drupal 7 site with a custom sub-theme off of the parent bootstrap theme.  I have added a few blocks to the footer and they are automatically pulled in to my site's footer which pulls the code from the default bootstrap footer (though I can't figure out where that template is in the bootstrap theme).  However when I create a custom region--footer.tpl.php in my sub-theme, I lose the blocks that I have added to the footer in the admin.  How can I use my custom footer template while also pulling in the footer blocks from the admin?

Comment: Admin theme is the same of your front theme ?

Comment: Yep, they use the same theme